# Getting google-drive file-id for a given file from windows (esp powershell)

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, google-drive-api

What is the easiest way to get a google drive file id for a given file on a google drive (on windows)?

In particular, using power-shell.

Cheers

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `files.list` REST method.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: Not what is being asked

Comment: Indeed - and I note that that solution doesn't work with applications deployed using click once.